# Google Sheets combine all selected rows into single cell separated by commas

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to combine all selected rows into a single cell.

```
A
B
C
D
E
...Z
```

or alternatively, all selected.

Into a single cell as A, B, C, D, E where I can copy its values.

I have tried to concat, and merge unsuccessfully, as merging deletes all values but A and concat only combines the instructed values.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer while looking into VB Scripts, for Google Sheets it's 
Google Apps Scripts

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#mergevertically